# End the current running task if timeout happens but not the future scheduled task

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have some task to be scheduled.I am using ScheduledExecutorService for this. Here I have some requirement.

1. Some task are scheduled at fixed delay.
2. Some task runs everyday at certain time.
3. Some task runs for fixed no. of days or fixed no. of period.
4. Cancel a task if it takes more time to execute then the assigned time

I have implemented the first three point as

```
   //schedule task at fixed delay or at certain time(by calculating the delay)
    final ScheduledFuture<?> a = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableClass,initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   //end task scheduler if it has executed for certain number of period ( endDelay` by calculting the timestamp to be cancelled)

    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        a.cancel(false);
                    }
                }, endDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But I am confused in the 4th requirement which says that cancel a certain task if it takes more then the assigned time to execute. I want to cancel the running task only timeout happens not the future scheduled task.Please suggest some idea.

I am using  ScheduledExecutorService and not allowed to use some other library.

Comment: You could collect the futures in some structure and have another task/thread periodically check for timeouts and if you detect one call `cancel()` on that future.

Comment: Additionally if your executor implementation is `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` you can set a couple of policies that define what do to with cancelled, stopped etc. tasks.

Comment: `getDelay()` inherited by `ScheduledFuture`. Can be called on the returned `ScheduledFuture` to get the remaining delay.